# What is the best way to check and retrieve the first item of a collection?

Tags: c#, linq, scope

I understand this is somewhat trivial but...

What the best way to get the reference the first item of a collection if any exist? Assume the collection contains items of a reference-type.

**Code Sample 1:**

```
if (collection.Any())
{
    var firstItem = collection.First();
    // add logic here
}
```

The above sample has two separate calls on the collection starting an iteration which complete as soon as the first is detected.

**Code Sample 2:**

```
var firstItem = collection.FirstOrDefault();
if (firstItem != null)
{
    // add logic here
}
```

The above sample only has a single call on the collection but introduces a variable that is unnecessarily in a wider scope.

Is there a best-practices related to this scenario? Is there a better solution?

Comment: If you really need the most fast code, you can take examples from answers, compile and open assemblies with ILDasm. You will see what is the most expensive.

Comment: I don't consider it that trivial - #1 has a race-condition and #2 doesn't work on every possible `<T>` (as you noted), so anything that helps people avoid these pitfalls is worthwhile.

Comment: Have you taken into account that `null` might be the first element in a collection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer the second example because it's more effecient in the general case.  It's possible that this collection is combination of many different delay evaluated LINQ queries such that even getting the first element requires a non-trivial amount of work.

Imagine for example that this collection is build from the following LINQ query

```
var collection = originalList.OrderBy(someComparingFunc);
```

Getting just the first element out of `collection` requires a full sort of the contents of `originalList`.  This full sort will occur each time the elements of `collection` are evaluated.

The first sample causes the potentially expensive collection to be evaluated twice: via the `Any` and `First` method.  The second sample only evaluates the collection once and hence I would choose it over the first.

Answer (score 3):

You could create an extension method like this:

```
public static bool TryGetFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, out T value)
{
    foreach (T elem in seq)
    {
        value = elem;
        return true;
    }
    value = default(T);
    return false;
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
int firstItem;
if (collection.TryGetFirst(out firstItem))
{
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what `FirstOrDefault` does (edit: except this handles value types as well. Good suggestion - I wonder why they didn't build this in?)

Comment: @Zooba,  it also handles IEnumerables that contain null (or default) values

Answer (score 2):

The second doesn't work on non-nullable value types (**Edit:** as you assumed - missed that the first time) and doesn't really have an alternative besides the first, which has a race-condition. There are two alternatives which are both suitable - selecting one or the other depends on how frequently you will get an empty sequence.

If it's a common or expected case where you get an empty enumeration, using a `foreach` loop is relatively neat:

```
foreach (var firstItem in collection)
{
    // add logic here
    break;
}
```

or if you really don't want the `break` in there (which is understandable):

```
foreach (var firstItem in collection.Take(1))
{
    // add logic here
}
```

If it is relatively unusual for it to be empty then a `try/catch` block should give the best performance (since exceptions are only expensive if they are actually raised - an unraised exception is practically free):

```
try
{
    var firstItem = collection.First();
    // add logic here
}
catch (InvalidOperationException) { }
```

A third option is to use an enumerator directly, though this should be identical to the `foreach` version and is slightly less clear:

```
using (var e = collection.GetEnumerator())
{
    if (e.MoveNext())
    {
        var firstItem = e.Current;
        // add logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: version 2 assumes that the collection has implemented the extension method First()

Comment: @tkeE2036 Version 2 assumes the collection implements `IEnumerable<T>` and that `System.Linq` has been imported. Based on the question, these are good assumptions.

Comment: "Version 2" in the earlier comments is now the third (`try/catch`), because I added another `foreach` approach.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I use this pattern:

```
foreach (var firstItem in collection) {
    // add logic here
    break;
}
```

It initiates only one iteration (so it's better than Code Sample 1) and the scope of the variable `firstItem` is limited inside the brackets (so it's better than Code Sample 2).

Comment: +1 for producing an identical code example to me :) (and doing it first, but I didn't see until I'd finished my own answer)

Comment: IMO, this is plain wrong!  If you see a loop when reading code it implies we expect to more often than not have more than one item in a collection. If the question is taken as  read it implies test and retrieve JUST the first item from a collection.

Comment: I am personally not a fan of this because it reduces readability of the code in the sense that someone reading this will see a foreach and assume that you are iterating over multiple elements. If your logic gets complex, a new person reading your code may miss the one line break; statement.

Comment: I think this is the worst approach because it sacrifices clear intent (IMO the most important quality of code) for the less relevant improvement in variable scope (which with "short enough" methods may not matter at all) and the even less important expected speed increase (totally irrelevant unless it's in the inner loop of a CPU-bound thread).

Comment: @Mitch Wheat. Sometimes it actually increases readability. I use this pattern when reading deep nested optional XML elements and I found that it reduces the amount of code significantly.

Comment: @linepogl: "Sometimes it actually increases readability." - No it doesn't. I see loop, I think multiple iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Or, as an extension to the solution from Gabe, make it use a lambda so you can drop the if:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static bool TryGetFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (T elem in seq)
        {
            if (action != null)
            {
                action(elem);
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
     List<int> ints = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

     ints.TryGetFirst<int>(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: I thought about this solution, but it's a bit slower, so I didn't use it.

Comment: Absolutely true, but the question is how often is the code used? It is important to differentiate between theoretical performance hits and real life performance hits. Also, instead of the lambda can you directly use an existing method too. It is good to see so many examples on this question though, options I hadn't think of yet!

Answer (score 0):

Since all generic `Collections` (ie: of type [System.Collections.ObjectModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)) have the `Count` member my preferred way of doing this is as follows:

```
Item item = null;
if(collection.Count > 0)
{
    item = collection[0];
}
```

This is safe is since all Collections will have both the `Count` and `Item` property. Its also very straight forward and easy for any other programmers reading your code to understand what your intent is.

Comment: As I commented on a similar answer that appears to have been deleted, this assumes that `collection` is actually a collection and not just an `IEnumerable<T>`. All generic collections implement `IEnumerable<T>`, so any solution that works and is clear for that will also work for any collection. The increased generality also lets you replace an `IList` with an `IEnumerable` without changing any code.

Comment: My understanding is that the 'Count' property potentially iterates the entire collection to retrieve the value. I'm not sure if this is true, but if so, then I imagine this is a fairly inefficient way to check if any exist. The linq method .Any() will return true if the first record exists without iterating the entire collection.

Answer (score 0):

Just did simple test on primitive type, and looks like your code sample #2 is fastest in this case (updated):

```
[TestFixture] public class SandboxTesting {
  #region Setup/Teardown
  [SetUp] public void SetUp() {
    _iterations = 10000000;
  }
  [TearDown] public void TearDown() {}
  #endregion
  private int _iterations;
  private void SetCollectionSize(int size) {
    _collection = new Collection<int?>();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      _collection.Add(i);
  }
  private Collection<int?> _collection;
  private void AnyFirst() {
    if(_collection.Any()) {
      int? firstItem = _collection.First();
      var x = firstItem;
    }
  }
  private void NullCheck() {
    int? firstItem = _collection.FirstOrDefault();
    if (firstItem != null) {
      var x = firstItem;
    }
  }
  private void ForLoop() {
    foreach(int firstItem in _collection) {
      var x = firstItem;
      break;
    }
  }
  private void TryGetFirst() {
    int? firstItem;
    if (_collection.TryGetFirst(out firstItem)) {
      var x = firstItem;
    }
  }    
  private TimeSpan AverageTimeMethodExecutes(Action func) {
    // clean up
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();

    // warm up 
    func();

    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < _iterations; i++) {
      func();
    }
    watch.Stop();
    return new TimeSpan(watch.ElapsedTicks/_iterations);
  }
  [Test] public void TimeAnyFirstWithEmptySet() {      
    SetCollectionSize(0);

    TimeSpan averageTime = AverageTimeMethodExecutes(AnyFirst);

    Console.WriteLine("Took an avg of {0} secs on empty set", avgTime);     
  }
  [Test] public void TimeAnyFirstWithLotsOfData() {
    SetCollectionSize(1000000);

    TimeSpan avgTime = AverageTimeMethodExecutes(AnyFirst);

    Console.WriteLine("Took an avg of {0} secs on non-empty set", avgTime);      
  }
  [Test] public void TimeForLoopWithEmptySet() {
    SetCollectionSize(0);

    TimeSpan avgTime = AverageTimeMethodExecutes(ForLoop);

    Console.WriteLine("Took an avg of {0} secs on empty set", avgTime);
  }
  [Test] public void TimeForLoopWithLotsOfData() {
    SetCollectionSize(1000000);

    TimeSpan avgTime = AverageTimeMethodExecutes(ForLoop);

    Console.WriteLine("Took an avg of {0} secs on non-empty set", avgTime);
  }
  [Test] public void TimeNullCheckWithEmptySet() {
    SetCollectionSize(0);

    TimeSpan avgTime = AverageTimeMethodExecutes(NullCheck);

    Console.WriteLine("Took an avg of {0} secs on empty set", avgTime);
  }
  [Test] public void TimeNullCheckWithLotsOfData() {
    SetCollectionSize(1000000);

    TimeSpan avgTime = AverageTimeMethodExecutes(NullCheck);

    Console.WriteLine("Took an avg of {0} secs on non-empty set", avgTime);
  }
  [Test] public void TimeTryGetFirstWithEmptySet() {
    SetCollectionSize(0);

    TimeSpan avgTime = AverageTimeMethodExecutes(TryGetFirst);

    Console.WriteLine("Took an avg of {0} secs on empty set", avgTime);
  }
  [Test] public void TimeTryGetFirstWithLotsOfData() {
    SetCollectionSize(1000000);

    TimeSpan averageTime = AverageTimeMethodExecutes(TryGetFirst);

    Console.WriteLine("Took an avg of {0} secs on non-empty set", avgTime);
  }
}
public static class Extensions {
  public static bool TryGetFirst<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, out T value) {
    foreach(T elem in seq) {
      value = elem;
      return true;
    }
    value = default(T);
    return false;
  }
}
```

**AnyFirst**
 NonEmpty: 00:00:00.0000262 seconds
 EmptySet: 00:00:00.0000174 seconds

**ForLoop**
NonEmpty: 00:00:00.0000158 seconds
EmptySet: 00:00:00.0000151 seconds

**NullCheck**
NonEmpty: 00:00:00.0000088 seconds
EmptySet: 00:00:00.0000064 seconds

**TryGetFirst**
NonEmpty: 00:00:00.0000177 seconds
EmptySet: 00:00:00.0000172 seconds

Comment: You'll need to run each of `AnyFirst()`, `NullCheck()` and `ForLoop()` a lot more than once to get reasonable results. You'll also want to compare the performance against an empty sequence, as well as a non-empty sequence.

Comment: @Zooba, yes, I agree, this was just initial testing I did before left work. I want to average over a lot of runs, different test cases (empty set), and test with JaredPar's order example. I will try and update soon.